# asyncapi/react-component -Uncaught EvalError - Content Security Policy

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to integrate https://www.npmjs.com/package/@asyncapi/react-component component in my existing react app but I am getting below error while running the app in browser. I am using below content security policy in my code.

CODE:---

```
'content-security-policy': [{
    value: [
      "default-src 'none'",
      'connect-src *',
      "prefetch-src 'self'",
      "font-src 'self' data: fonts.gstatic.com",
      "img-src 'self' data:",
      "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'",
      "style-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com"
    ].join(';')
  }]
```

ERROR:--

> Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'".

Please suggest how to fix this kind of issue.